# How can i locate angular root element?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, angular-library

I wanted to use angular lib with robot framework, but I get this error:

`Library AngularJSLibrary root_selector=app-root` and I just use a simple step:

```
|Page Should Contain Element | ${userpanel}
```

the only difference is in highlighted:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any Robot Framework Script to share in the form of an [mcve].

Comment: Library     AngularJSLibrary  root_selector=app-root
and i just use a simple step:
Page Should Contain Element    ${userpanel}

Comment: the only different is in highlited
https://imgshare.io/image/NZRBLy

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the information from the comments in it? In addition it seems that your example is incomplete, based on the AngularJSLibrary [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-angularjs/)

Comment: Are you certain you're testing an [AgularJS](https://angularjs.org/) application and not an [Angular](https://angular.io/) application? The JS version is an much older version. The AngularJS library only works for the older AngularJS version, not the more recent Angular one.

Comment: thanks the raising

i attach a screenshoot about the two web app:
https://ibb.co/93yLncx

on the left app the angular is working but on the right is not ok, but the they are similar source code